# Does deleting right censoring data make it to be left truncated?

Tags: survival, censoring, definition, truncation

If data have right censoring and complete data, I delete the right censored ones. Does it make the data to be left truncated? And why?

Comment: Are the censoring levels constant or can they vary?  What forms of censoring are you considering?

Comment: @whuber I'm considering constant censoring.Length of survival is observed until a certain time point.